# moment ago in VueJS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following in a vue file

`<p class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ readableDate(message.created_at) }}</p>`

and

```
 methods: {
    readableDate (date) {
      return (new Date(date)).toLocaleString()
    }
  }
```

What I want is to show X second/min/hour ago as opposed to the full date/time. Ive considered various options but wondering if anyone has a clean simple way other than using momentjs

Comment: This depends on what you define as "clean and simple". Using momentjs is a valid, clean and simple solution. It adds about 232 kB (66 kB gzipped) in filesize if this is too much for your application and you only want this "time ago" method you could extract it and create your own method. But I personally don't see a reason for this. The way you asked the question is more a opinion based answer.

Comment: Im going to be honest after writing this I went and tried momentjs. I like it truly but I also feel inclined to build my own. My issue comes down to having a bunch of 3rd party packages where I am at the mercy of others. So when I am building something I try and write as much as I can. For now I’m going to stick with MomentJS, But add this as a future task to resolve later.